# Is there a way to import SQL script into MDF database in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

I created a "Service-Based Database" (.MDF) in Visual Studio and now want to import a SQL script into it, but cannot find any way to do this:

- I can right-click on the .mdf file and choose "New Query" but there is no place to copy in query text as in Management Studio

Does the Visual Studio 2008 Database Explorer have a way to enter or import SQL query text?

Comment: Do you want to execute the SQL in the file against the MDF?

Comment: I also wish to solve this problem & yes I do want to execute the sql in the file against the MDF

Answer (score 2):

When you choose "New Query", the default behavior is to open the Query Editor. So you have to close the Add Table. After that, you should see a window with four panes - Diagram, Criteria, SQL and Result pane. You should be able to put your script to SQL pane and run from it. The Studio may complain about being unable to parse the script, just ignore it and hit ok, the script should run.

If you cannot see these panes, ensure you have "Query Designer" toolbar enabled and "SQL pane" button pushed.

However, I would recommend installing SQL Management Studio, there is a free express version available.

Comment: Thanks Mate, We can ignore visual studio paring error. It works :) Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just attach the database directly to your SQL Server (or SQLExpress) and then copy the database objects. The  detach from the sql server again.